# Eloquent javascript tabs exercise

Tags: javascript, tabs, event-handling, eloquent

Eloquent Javascript ch.14 exercise #3 answers, Making tabs.

```
    <div id="wrapper">
  <div data-tabname="one">Tab one</div>
  <div data-tabname="two">Tab two</div>
  <div data-tabname="three">Tab three</div>
</div>
<script>
  function asTabs(node) {
    var tabs = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < node.childNodes.length; i++) {
      var child = node.childNodes[i];
      if (child.nodeType == document.ELEMENT_NODE)
        tabs.push(child);
    }

    var tabList = document.createElement("div");
    tabs.forEach(function(tab, i) {
      var button = document.createElement("button");
      button.textContent = tab.getAttribute("data-tabname");
      button.addEventListener("click", function() { selectTab(i); });
      tabList.appendChild(button);
    });
    node.insertBefore(tabList, node.firstChild);

    function selectTab(n) {
      tabs.forEach(function(tab, i) {
        if (i == n)
          tab.style.display = "";
        else
          tab.style.display = "none";
      });
      for (var i = 0; i < tabList.childNodes.length; i++) {
        if (i == n)
          tabList.childNodes[i].style.background = "violet";
        else
          tabList.childNodes[i].style.background = "";
      }
    }
    selectTab(0);
  }
  asTabs(document.querySelector("#wrapper"));
</script>
```

Would someone mind explaining the significance of this line:

```
button.addEventListener("click", function() { selectTab(i); });
```

Question 1: This looks like a simple callback, why can't I simply place a call to selectTab(i)?

```
button.addEventListener("click", selectTab(n));
```

Question 2: Why doesn't the function just return the selecTab function ie:

```
button.addEventListener("click", function() { return selectTab(n); });
```

Question 3: Why can't I pass an event object into selectTab like this?

```
button.addEventListener("click", selectTab(event));
function selectTab(event){console.log(event.target)}
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: 1. it's about when: you need the function to delay the action until the event happens instead of firing at bind time. 2. there's lots of ways to code, who know why this is how it was choosen... 3. is related to 1: there is no _event_ until an event handler executes, so you need an event handler function. that all said, this doesn't seem very "Eloquent"; it uses old interfaces and way too much code to do something so simple...

Answer (score 0):

Thanks dandavis. I was able to come up with this after your explanation:

```
button.addEventListener("click", function(event){ selectTab(event);});
function selectTab(event){
        console.log(event.target.textContent);
    }
```

Probably not eloquent, but I understand it and it works!